# AngularJs: bind server-side rendered html to iframe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, html-rendering

my angular app is an html editor which sends the template to a server where it is rendered with dynamic data and returned to the client where it should be inserted into an iframe (for preview purpose). ng-bind-html seams not to work in combination with an iframe. is there a way to set the content of an iframe dynamically with angularjs?

edit:
the main problem of these templates is that they correspond to completly independent html documents (doctype, css, markup, etc.); hence it is necessary to encapsulate the rendered result within some kind of sandbox.

Comment: the main problem of these templates is that they correspond to completly independent html documents (doctype, css, markup, etc.); hence it is necessary to encapsulate the rendered result within some kind of sandbox.

Comment: [here is another question][1] which demonstrates how you can send content to iFrame.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125910/is-it-possible-to-update-angularjs-expressions-inside-of-an-iframe

Answer (score -3):

I don't know how to send content to `iframe` but you can use ng-include instead of iframe.

```
<div ng-include="frameUrl" ></div>
```