# getting angular scope instance inside iframe

Tags: angularjs, iframe, scope

I have an app where things are being binded using angular js. There is a iframe inside that another angular app is running. Can i get angular scope on parent window so that I can change scope variables for iframe app

Comment: Have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437594/angularjs-call-other-scope-which-in-iframe?

Comment: but there is no answer or useful comment

Comment: @Abhishekbhutra, actually there is something useful at the end of the question. Also, that doesn't justify duplicating the question...

Comment: I've answered on that question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21733164/1426570

Comment: Thanks Urigo, but its too late to reply here. I already have implemented the same. I missed to put an answer. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs: call other scope which in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437594/angularjs-call-other-scope-which-in-iframe)