# Angular, how to bridge two iframes?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

For example, edit the text input of iframe A, the content text of iframe B change to the same value. Of course, they are all on the same domain.

Comment: I think that you need a server to coordinate iframes

Comment: You should avoid IFrames at first, if possible :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437594/angularjs-call-other-scope-which-in-iframe

Comment: @Georgi-it If you are developing something like Webflow, it's hard to avoid iframe.

Comment: @Yad Smood I still think it can be avoided I do not say that it will be easier, but is avoidable.