# How to call iframe controller function from parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a iframe in my parent window. I use angularjs on both the parent and iframe. Normally, when i call a function in iframe I use

```
document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.function_name();
```

I dont know how to call a angularjs controller function. My controller in the iframe looks like this

```
app.controller('UserController',['$scope', function($scope){
    this.showOptions = function(type){
    alert(type);
}
```

how can I call `this.showoptions` in the iframe from parent.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437594/angularjs-call-other-scope-which-in-iframe